# Enviar registros a varias tabalas- mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

quisiera saber como se envía de un solo formulario a distintas tablas.

por ejemplo tengo el siguiente código podrían agregar un ejemplo enviando registros diferentes a dos tablas.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdnutriologo") or
    die("Problemas con la conexión");

mysqli_query($conexion,"insert into expediente(id_exp,peso,edad,estatura,fecha_registro,sexo,objetivo) values 
                       ('$_POST[id_exp]','$_POST[peso]','$_POST[edad]','$_POST[estatura]','$_POST[fecha_registro]','$_POST[sexo]','$_POST[objetivo]')")



  or die("Problemas en el select".mysqli_error($conexion));

mysqli_close($conexion);

echo "El paciente fue dado de alta.";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. El código compartido podría ser vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques.

Comment: ¿Por qué no tener diferentes insert para cada tabla?

Comment: Bueno solo es una tarea que dejo el profesor por la seguridad leere despues sobre eso.

Comment: Ok. Comprendo que la tarea tiene prioridad ahora mismo, pero te aseguro que lo que aprenderás sobre inyección SQL y cómo prevenirla va a ser una lección más valiosa para el futuro.

Comment: Ahora, por favor incluye algo más de información a la pregunta: ¿qué datos se envían desde el formulario a la página? ¿cuáles son las datas en las que se tienen que guardar datos? ¿qué datos irían en qué tablas? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: vale lo hare...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tal, no existen sentencias SQL para insertar en 2 tablas, aún que se podría lograr con procedures y cascada en función de las necesidades.

Si lo que quieres es insertar registros en más de una tabla deberás hacer un insert por cada tabla.

Es decir:

```
<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect("datos conexion");

mysqli_query($conexion, "primer insert tabla 1");
mysqli_query($conexion, "primer insert tabla 2");
mysqli_query($conexion, "primer insert tabla 3");
```

Para garantizar la consistencia de los datos, cuando estos son dependientes podemos utilizar transacciones, para poder garantizar que se ejecutan todas las consultas correctamente, o en caso de que algo falle poder decidir que hacer, realizando rollback o otra acción.

```
/* Deshabilitar autocommit */
mysqli_autocommit($conexion, false);

/* Flag */
$error = false;

if( !mysqli_query($conexion, "consulta 1") ) {
    $error = true;
}
if( !mysqli_query($conexion, "consulta 2") ) {
    $error = true;
}

if($error) {
    /* Revertir los cambios*/
    mysqli_rollback($conexion);

    echo "Algo falló";
    exit;
}

/* Consignar insert */
mysqli_commit($conexion);
```